# configure_file error on make install while compiling nfs-ganesha

Tags: c, linux, cmake, nfs

## My objective

I want to compile and install nfs-ganesha from source on a Oracle Linux machine.

## Steps to reproduce

- Using Oracle Linux Server release 7.4

1. Download nfs-ganesha from github: https://github.com/nfs-ganesha/nfs-ganesha
2. Follow steps from line 56 to 61 on this guide (just a normal compilation and installation): https://github.com/nfs-ganesha/nfs-ganesha/blob/next/src/COMPILING_HOWTO.txt
3. At some point, you might receive an error that you're missing userspace-rcu. Do `sudo yum install userspace-rcu userspace-rcu-devel` to fix it.
4. When I run the last command (`make install`) I get the following error:

## Error

```
bash-4.2$ make install
[  3%] Built target MainServices
normal build output...
[100%] Built target fsalmem
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Debug"
-- Installing: /etc/ganesha/ganesha.conf
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:54 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file


make: *** [install] Error 1
```

## Some insights

I opened `cmake_install.cmake` to see what is failing, here is a fragment of the code:

I marked the faulty line with an arrow

```
IF(NOT CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT OR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT}" STREQUAL "Unspecified")
  
        set(_destfile "/etc/ganesha/ganesha.conf")
        if (NOT "$ENV{DESTDIR}" STREQUAL "")
            # prepend install root prefix with install-time DESTDIR
            set(_destfile "$ENV{DESTDIR}//etc/ganesha/ganesha.conf")
        endif ()
        if (EXISTS ${_destfile})
            message(STATUS "Skipping: ${_destfile} (already exists)")
            execute_process(COMMAND "/usr/bin/cmake" -E compare_files
                /home/carlhida/Documents/ganesha/src/config_samples/ganesha.conf.example ${_destfile} RESULT_VARIABLE _diff)
            if (NOT "${_diff}" STREQUAL "0")
                message(STATUS "Installing: ${_destfile}.example")
                configure_file(/home/carlhida/Documents/ganesha/src/config_samples/ganesha.conf.example ${_destfile}.example COPYONLY)
            endif ()
        else ()
            message(STATUS "Installing: ${_destfile}")
            # install() is not scriptable within install(), and
            # configure_file() is the next best thing
-------->>> configure_file(/home/carlhida/Documents/ganesha/src/config_samples/ganesha.conf.example ${_destfile} COPYONLY)
            # TODO: create additional install_manifest files?
        endif ()
    
ENDIF(NOT CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT OR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT}" STREQUAL "Unspecified")
```

What I found on this function is that it copies one file to another, but I'm not sure how to get more information from the error. My main concern is that it might have to do with permissions but when I use `sudo`, I just get:

```
bash-4.2$ sudo make install
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/carlhida/Documents/ganesha/src" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
```

So I think it is not related to that.

## Pivoting questions

Is there a way to know what exactly is the problem with those files? I would really appreciate if anyone knows how to get a verbose output on those errors.

#### Thank you for your help!

Comment: You should remove the Oracle tag. That tag refers to Oracle RDBMS. It **does not** have anything to do with Oracl Linux, which is derived from RedHat Enterprise Linux.

Comment: I guess your location is the wrong directory, when doing 'make install'. .... Please se my results  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rigMiJZzow9tPiaHUt3vOp-C6TOQulYg?usp=sharing

Comment: The error "Problem configuring file" is about permissions. The error "The source directory ... does not exist" is about wrong directory where you run `sudo make install`, as stated by the previous commenter.

Comment: I removed the oracle tag, and I tried doing `sudo make install -C /home/carlhida/Documents/buildganesha/`. I got the following error:
`make: *** /home/carlhida/Documents/buildganesha/: Permission denied.  Stop.` It seems it actually has to do with permissions. (I also can't use `su` because I think I don't have full admin privileges in my vm.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by moving the repo's folder and the build folder to a directory called `/scratch`. Then I issued the command again by being root. It installed correctly this time.